# CentOS 7 doesn't recognize new Active Directory accounts/settings

Tags: windows, centos, active-directory, domain, centos7

I joined a CentOS 7 system to a Windows domain by syncing the time with the DC and running `realm join --user=admin@mydomain.local mydomain.local`. This allowed me to authenticate my login to the CentOS system using my Active Directory accounts.

However, any AD account or group membership added after the initial join are not recognized by the CentOS system. I have to run `realm leave` and rejoin the domain in order for those accounts/settings to be recognized.

How can I force CentOS to authenticate against the DC each time using the latest AD configuration?

Comment: Is it possibly a caching issue? Does running "sss_cache --users" or "sss_cache --groups" show any change?

Comment: You should probably add any relevant logs to your question to increase the chances some helps.